# Merge Multiple XML files in to one XML file in the azure storage using azure functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, concatenation, azure-storage

I am learning azure functions as a part of it, i want to merge two different xml files of same xml structures in to a single xml file. Can some one please help me how to do that using azure functions ?

While merging the xml through async method, i am unable to open the xmldocument using XmlDocument.Open as there is no definition Open for XmlDocument. How do we open the xmldocument data ?

This is my code and i got stuck at while open the xmldocument through memorystream

```
        private async Task<IList> MergeFileAsync(CloudBlobContainer container, string[] blobFiles)
        {
            XmlDocument outputDocument = new XmlDocument();

            foreach(String fileblob in blobFiles)
            {
                string file = $"" + blobFiles;

                CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(file);
                using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);

                    string contents = blockBlob.DownloadTextAsync().Result;

                      //stuck here
                    var inputDocument = XmlDocument.Open(memoryStream, XmlDocument.Import);
                    

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please specify what error are you getting and on which line you are having the problem.

Comment: Hi, I am getting the error at line
var inputDocument = XmlDocument.Open(memoryStream, XmlDocument.Import);

Error saying theta XmlDocument doesnot contain the definition for Open

I am using this similary as we have for pdf merge , so i am trying to use that for xml merge also, but getting the above stated error.So please help me out how can go forwrd from here or is there any alternate where i can work on it....Thanks

Comment: Can you update the question with the information you have provided in the comment? Because your question does not meet the community standards. Unless it is updated it would be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you read the blob files and add the blob content to the single separate file. If you want to combine the excel file, we have two approaches to achieve. Either you can use **`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`** package and using **`File Stream`**.

Here I have collected the file from blob and adding content of the file in separate file.

```cs
string localPath = "<File path>";
string fileName = "<FiletoCombine>";
string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localPath, fileName);
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
string containerName = "<Your container Name>";

BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

var val = containerClient.GetBlobs();
foreach (BlobItem blobItem in val)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\t" + blobItem.Name);
    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobItem.Name);
    string downloadFilePath = localFilePath.Replace(".xlsx", blobItem.Name.Replace(".xlsx","")+"<Filename.xlsx>");
    Console.WriteLine("\nDownloading blob to\n\t{0}\n", downloadFilePath);
    await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(downloadFilePath);
}
```

Using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** :

```cs
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView3.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 4, j + 1] = dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
    }
}

xlWorkBook.SaveAs(downloadFilePath);
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();
xlWorkSheet = null;
xlWorkBook = null;
xlApp = null;
```

Refer to [C# Corner article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/datatable-to-excel-excel-formatting) for `using stream` to add content to excel file.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already got xmldocument content, you have to instantiate xmldocument with content.

```cs
string contents = blockBlob.DownloadTextAsync().Result;
outputDocument.LoadXml(contents);
```